# SQLite db high scores table not inserting and sorting correctly - Android

Tags: java, android, sqlite, sorting, insert

My db keeps the top 10 records.  When the db is empty, the db records the scores and inserts them correctly all the way until there is 10 records.  Then, for example, when the db has 10 scores, and the user gets a score that should be the new #1 score, it just replaces the current #1 score with the new one instead of inserting and bumping everything below it down one and deleting the bottom score.  Hopefully I explained that well but if not just comment and I will try to clarify further.

My question is how can I get the high scores to perform correctly as in when the high scores is full with 10 records already, a new record is inserted into the correct spot and the rest below it are all moved down one with the last record getting bumped off completely (since it is the new #11).

**DatabaseHelper.java**

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper { 

    SQLiteDatabase db;

    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 6; 
    private static final String DB_NAME = "test3"; 
    private static final String DB_PATH = "/data/data/matt.lyons.bibletrivia/databases/";
    private static final String TABLE = "HighscoresList"; 

    // Table columns names. 
    private static final String RANK = "_id"; 
    private static final String SCORE = "score"; 
    private static final String PERCENTAGE = "percentage";
    private static final String TOTAL_SCORE = "total_score";
    private static final String CATEGORY = "category";

    //Constructor for a DatabaseHelper.
    public DatabaseHelper(Context context) { 
        super(context, DB_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION); 
    }

    //Open the DB so it is editable.
    public SQLiteDatabase openDB() {
        db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        return db;
    }

    //Delete a selected one row.
    public void delete(long lowScore) {
        lowScore = getLowest();
        db.delete(TABLE, TOTAL_SCORE + "=" + lowScore, null);
    }

    //Sort rows in order of the TOTAL_SCORE column.
    public long getLowest() {
        Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + TABLE + " ORDER BY " + TOTAL_SCORE, null);
        long count = c.getCount();
        long lowScore = -1;
        if(count == 10) {
            c.moveToLast();
            lowScore = c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex(TOTAL_SCORE));
        }
        return lowScore;
    }

    //Calculate the TOTAL_SCORE based on the SCORE and PERCENTAGE of a game.
    public long calculateTotalScore(long score, int percentage) {
        long i;
        return i = (percentage * 1000) + score;
    }

    //Check if new record makes the top 10.
    public long check(long score, int percentage, long sum) {
        Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT " + TOTAL_SCORE + " FROM " + TABLE, null);
        long count = c.getCount();
        long low_score;
        if(count == 10) {
            c.moveToLast();
            low_score = c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex(TOTAL_SCORE));
            return low_score;
        } else {
            return count;
        }
    }

    //Insert new record.
    public long insert(long score, int percentage, long total_score, String category) {
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(SCORE, score);
        values.put(PERCENTAGE, percentage);
        values.put(TOTAL_SCORE, total_score);
        values.put(CATEGORY, category);

        return db.insert(TABLE, null, values);
    }

    //Create the table and all columns.
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + TABLE + " ("
                + RANK + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"
                + SCORE + " LONG,"
                + PERCENTAGE + " INTEGER,"
                + CATEGORY + " STRING,"
                + TOTAL_SCORE + " LONG"
                + ");");
    }
}
```

**Results.java**

```
public class Results extends Activity {

    DatabaseHelper dh;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        dh = new DatabaseHelper(this);
        dh.openDB();
        showResults();
    }

    public void showResults() {

        total_score = dh.calculateTotalScore(score, percentage);
        if(dh.getLowest() == -1) {
            dh.insert(score, percentage, total_score, category);
        } else {
            dh.delete(dh.getLowest());
            dh.insert(score, percentage, total_score, category);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not just:

```
"SELECT LIMIT 10 * FROM " + TABLE + " ORDER BY TOTAL_SCORE DESC"
```

That way you'd get the top ten scores without having to insert/delete all the time?

Comment: Are you saying not to delete records and just keep all of them and just display the top 10?  If that is what you are saying, would that not ow the game down or take up too much memory if the user plays 1000 or 2000 times?

Comment: This I wouldn't suggest is the best way. Probably not too bad with newer devices where there is lots of storage but overtime the database has the potential to get quite big (although if that's all its storing then would prob take quite a long time). It may be easier to do it like this and then perform another query to find the lowest score if you have more than 10 rows

Comment: I will take all that into consideration.  But looking at my code, can you see why it is not performing correctly?

Comment: The rowsize is tiny, say 25-30 bytes; so you add a couple of K over time, it's no big deal.

Comment: Wow, never thought of that.  So each of my tiny rows are just probably 25-30 bytes?  You're right, that is next to nothing and probably should not even be a worry of mine.